# Warning message by using setMethod

Tags: r, reference-class

If I run the folowing code in the first time, I get a warning on setMethod:

```
Warning message:
In getPackageName(environment(fdef)) :
  Create package name, ‘2013-09-18 09:29:59’, if nothing there

B.getFields<-function(keys){
  vars<-mget(names(.refClassDef@fieldClasses), envir = attr(.self, ".xData"))
  return(vars[keys])
}

B<-setRefClass(Class = "B"
              ,fields = list(var1 = "character")
              ,methods = list(getFields=B.getFields
                               ,initialize=function(...) {
                                   usingMethods("getFields")
                                   callSuper(...)
                                 }
                               )
)  
setGeneric("getFields", function(object, ...) standardGeneric("getFields"))
setMethod(getFields, "list", function(object, ...) lapply(object,getFields,...))
```

Comment: Not reproducible on my system, either with R-3.0.1 or R-2.15.3. But I've already seen this message. Is it in a package ?  Are you using devtools ?

Comment: I dont load devtools and now I see I get this behavior only by using RStudio (R-3.0.1).

Comment: not reproducible using rstudio 0.98.308, on R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)